# Clicking on multiple links in one class in Appium java

Tags: java, appium, android-testing

I am facing an issue, In this case terms & conditions and privacy policy. two links are part of one class only and I am not able to click on privacy policy, but terms & conditions click works all the time by using that id.[image]

Comment: I faced this issue long ago. Can’t say I recall a solution other than having the dev team code it differently. Upvoting and subscribing in case there is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this since Appium recognises it a a single element.
Luckily, you can do the following steps:

- Find the TextView element
- Determine the position of the elements top-left corner
- Determine the TextView width and height
- Calculate approximate coordinates for `Privacy policy` link based on width/height and start position (top-left corner)
- Use the Actions
  API tap method to click by coordinates

There is an [article](https://appiumpro.com/editions/119-using-a-tap-by-location-helper-for-working-with-unresponsive-elements) from Appium team that addresses a similar issue and provides Java code sample.